# Connecting Linux and Android through Wifi-Direct (BeagleBone Black and Android-app)

Tags: android, linux, beagleboneblack, wifi-direct, wifip2p

For a quadcopter application, an FPV system is being built for custom Android app. The problem is in the connection between BeagleBone's Angstrom Linux and Android App through Edimax EW-7811Un Wifi device.

Wifi-Direct apparently supports the connection if just one of the two devices is WiFi-Direct-certified (has an internal access point). But, Sony phone's website (The phone on which app is being deployed) suggests that both devices must be WiFi-Direct compliant.

Some of the relevant materials can be found at [WiFi organization's website](http://www.wi-fi.org/file/wi-fi-certified-wi-fi-direct-personal-portable-wi-fi-to-connect-devices-anywhere-anytime-2014), [Sony phone's website](http://support.sonymobile.com/global-en/xperiamdual/userguide/Connecting-to-wireless-networks/) and [Android developer's official website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#createGroup%28android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener%29).

While modifying etc/network/interfaces, something went wrong and SSH is not working properly now. Before that (as far as memory recollects), wpa_supplicant was working and wpa_cli was not working well and both phone and BeagleBone weren't discovering each other. So, the problem is now in the connection. Can you please guide me and let me know if a new WiFi device is to be purchased (if so, the name of the device as well) or if it can be resolved with Android and Linux codes? (You are humbly requested to include the relevant code snippets too) [Two android devices equipped with WiFi-Direct are getting paired]

It is not clear in some [question(s)](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/31877144/how-to-set-up-a-wifi-direct-connection-between-android-and-linux) if the problem is mainly because of drivers like RTL8192CU. You are also requested to let me know if both devices must be WiFi-Direct certified always (and why).

Finally, a big-thanks to StackOverflow community for the simplification of entire process of software development.(My entire app got over without much difficulties mainly because of StackOverflow)

[Please note that this is my first proper post on StackOverflow. Please consider flagging this question if you find this question irrelevant or wasted your time]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, an answer has been provided officially by Edimax. We are thankful to Edimax for their frank response. The image attached explains the issue.[image]